# How to test Red5 server externally

Tags: red5, rtmp

I have installed red5 server on my localhost on which an xampp running. I can access port 80 externally so anyone knowing my id can access my web directory. However, an external computer cannot connect to my red5 I believe as I have a the videowhisper script installed and while I can connect to rtmp server locally, an external user cannot connect.

Is there a way to test the external connection to rtmp server from my computer? Or even there is and I cannot connect externally how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ping 1935, or so I have not found a way to.  My best answer is the telnet from a remote device using 1935 as a port

that would be(in CL):

telnet ipaddress port

if it connects it will give you the output about the escape character.  That means You are connected.

Though this may not be the recognized solution, it has worked for me, as a quick and dirty answer.

Answer (score 1):

RTMP works on port 1935 not port 80 unless tunnelling is specified. Have you tried pinging 1935 from the external machine?

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You must open ports 5080 and 1935 both on:

1. your RED5 web server and...
2. optionally (if any) network router, depending on your network topology;

If your web RED5 server stands behind a gateway you must open these two ports on your gateway as well in order to access RED5 from outside this network.